# Why would a function of a parent class not be found in the child class when used like this in PHP: $this->function_name()

Tags: php, function, class

I'm looking at some PHP code. There is a class LQDM_Shortcodes_Run_Base that extends WDS_Shortcodes. It then attempts to use the parent classes' public function `att`. In PhpStorm it alerts me that

> Method `att` not found in `LQDM_Shortcodes_Run_Base`

Why isn't it found? The child class does call the parent's constructor within its own constructor:

```
public function __construct( LQDM_Sermons $sermon ) {
  $this->sermons = $sermons;
  parent::__construct();
}
```

The call in the child class looks like:

```
protected function get_sermon() {
  $sermon_id = $this->att( 'sermon_id' );
  ...
}
```

The parent classes' function looks like this:

```
class WDS_Shortcodes {
  ...
  public function att( $att, $default = null ) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does it throw any error? Or it's only php storm? Are there any other methods being called in LQDM_Shortcodes_Run_Base?

Comment: No errors, works fine at run-time. `LQDM_Shortcodes_Run_Base` has only the `__construct` and `hooks` methods, though the latter does call the hooks methods on two other classes like so: `$this->run-->hooks();` and `$this->admin->hooks();`

Comment: Classes are ok. It seems to me, that it's only some issue of php storm.

Comment: Make sure none folder holding those classes is excluded. Try to invalidate caches if there may be a corrupted index.